# Probability: Understanding the difference between "exactly x amount" vs " distinct sequences"

Tags: probability

Consider the two problems:

> How many distinct sequences can we make using $3$ letter "A"s and $5$
>   letter "B"s? (AAABBBBB, AABABBBB, etc.)

and

> There are $20$ black cell phones and $30$ white cell phones in a store. An
>   employee takes $10$ phones at random. Find the probability that there
>   will be exactly $4$ black cell phones among the chosen phones.

I know that the first one can be thought of as: "How many ways can I put $3$ letter A's into $8$ blank spaces, while the blank spaces represent the B's"?  Which is $\binom{8}{3}$.

And the second one can be thought of as "The number of ways to get a combination of $(b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4, w_5, w_6)$ where the order is irrelevant because we only want the specific phones."  Which is $P(A) = \frac{P(4B \cap 6W)}{\binom{50}{10}} = \frac{\binom{20}{4} \binom{30}{6}}{\binom{50}{10}}$.

**My question is: Why is there a difference between the counting the events between the first and second problem?  For the second problem, why isn't it sufficient to just says there's $\binom{20}{4}$ ways to get a black phone and have the rest be white phones just like in the first problem?**

Comment: Your ${20 \choose 4}$ is a count not a probability.  And I am not sure what you think it is a count of.

Comment: In the question I'm asking what's the difference between the counting methods, why can I use $8C3$ in the first problem, and in the second one $20C4 * 30C6$ instead of just $20C4$?

Answer (score 0):

The essential difference here is that you not just choose 4 particular black phones out of the total number of black ones available, but you also need to choose 6 particular white ones out of the total amount available.

These are two independent choices; you lose the latter considering just binomial coefficient $\binom{20}4$ as a number of possible outcomes.